# Like on Inner Join Using Postcodes

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, inner-join, sql-like

I have 2 tables both with postcodes table 1 has the full post code and table 2 has  only the area part of the post code the first 2 to 4 characters seperated by a space.
Like so 
Table 1 'bb1 2ef' table 2 has just the area part first 2 - 4 characters
Table 2 'bb1'

I want to join these tables based on this. Initially i thought i could do a like clause on the join but cant seem to make that work.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Users AS u
INNER JOIN tbl_AdvisorsTeritories AS at
ON u.Postcode Like at.Postcode'%'
```

Comment: what does not work? do you get an error? if yes, which

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `LEFT`

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Users AS u
INNER JOIN tbl_AdvisorsTeritories AS at
ON LEFT(u.Postcode,3) = at.Postcode
```